# Creating a filter to capture all URLs

Tags: java, struts, websphere

I'm trying to capture all the URLs requested to WAS. I'm running a web app over WAS 6.0 and iIdefined a filter like this in the web.xml

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>StatusValidationFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.test.StatusValidationFilter</filter-class>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>StatusValidationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when I'm get a 404 error the filter isn't called, is like the WAS just break the app execution, so the question is, is the filter correctly configured?

If I try a .do url is working but if I try a url that generates a 404 error the filter isn't called.

Comment: i am wondering what you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter seems ok. But it is a bad practice to handle errors within a filter.

You should use the [`<error-page>` tag](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Seterrorpageinwebxml.htm).

So, this way, during the redirection the filter chain is still maintained.

Comment: Is working now, was a problem of my enviroment, and your answer is the correct one